# Upload image using postman

Tags: mongodb, postman

Hi I got this error whenever i want to upload images in NODE JS (MongoDB)using postman could anyone explain .  Below is the screenshot of the error.
 I use the header content type = image/png and use the raw to upload image

> [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/pavithra/node-mobile/uploads/posts/2209fb177948bc4801dc5f6c244013f5'
>   
>     at Error (native)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue looks like  **npm-permissions** issue. 
please refer this to manage permissions :-

[fixing-npm-permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)

Comment: Hi thank you for reply . I m not sure where this folder are reading from

Comment: In your error looks like "node-mobile" folder used by npm, you as a user don't have the permission to write in that folder which is{node-mobile/uploads/post}, where you trying to upload your image file.

Comment: you need permission to write, so you need change the owner to you from npm. for that you need to execute steps given in the link. I think "Option 1: Change the permission to npm's default directory"  can solve your problem.

Comment: In the given link, follow Option 1 . hope it will help.

Comment: Hi thank you @gajju_15 its working like a charm now after i grant the permission to the folder

Comment: you can accept the answer if it solved your issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing some kind of authentication required to `POST` data to the server.